# change the color of the "upvote" and "downvote" button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I voted up just now, I noticed the color of the upvote is almost the same blue as the background blue of the website and I can barely see if the upvote was clicked.

**Can the color of the upvote/downvote button be changed to a color that is more noticeable somehow (or has more contrast)?**

Comment: Would you include a screenshot of what you're seeing. Also curious to know the browser/OS you're on. For me, the vote buttons are on a white background for the center box, and the blue background is only visible outside that box in the last 10% or so of the side borders.